# Not adding the 'active' class with javascript(jquery)

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I don't know why the code don't add the class `active` but doesn't give me any error.

I can `console.log` the `activeLinkId`, but it won't add the class.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav-links ul li a").mouseover(function() {
        var activeLinkId = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".link-img img" + activeLinkId).addClass("active");
        $(".link-img img").removeClass("active");
      });
    });
```

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
        font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
        background-color: #201d14;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .link-img img{
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .toggle{
        position: fixed;
        right: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .toggle span{
        position: absolute;
        width: 48px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .toggle span:nth-child(2){
        top: 10px;
    }
    .toggle span:nth-child(3){
        top: 20px;
    }
    
    nav{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 99;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    
    .nav-links{
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 80px 100px 0 0;
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    
    ul li{
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
    
    ul li a{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: burlywood;
        transition: 0.7s;
    }
    
    .link-img{
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .link-img img{
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all ease 1s;
    }
    
    .link-img img.active{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
        
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .link-img{
        width: 70%;
        height:100%
      }
      .link-img img{
        width:100%;
      }
      ul{
        width:30%;
        padding-left:10px;
      }
      ul li a {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
    
    .hover-element{
        position: absolute;
        top: -50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #564a26;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="toggle">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <div class="nav-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactus">Contact us</a></li>
                </div>
                    <div class="hover-element">
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="link-img">
                    <img id="products" src="./img/imgtech1.jpg" alt="">
                    <img id="works" src="./img/imgtech2.jpg" alt="">
                    <img id="projects" src="./img/imgtech3.jpg" alt="">
                    <img id="contactus" src="./img/imgtech4.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it

Comment: actually you are adding the same libraries two times...

Comment: Yes i know,it was a test, i don't think this is the problem

Comment: Thanks for editing. The issue is because you're calling `removeClass()` on every `img` element after you add the class to the target `img`. Swap the order of those two lines of code.

Comment: `$(".link-img img" + activeLinkId)` this can be shortened to `$(activeLinkId)`. IDs have to be unique therefore selecting by id should always get a single, unique element.